# Error Publishing Add-in to Office Store - Mac OS Compatibility Issue

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-store

I'm having trouble publishing my add-in to the Office Store. When attempting to complete the process, I encounter the following error:

> Your offer does not work in Office for Mac connected to an M365 subscription. OSx Version: 13.2 Ventura, Office Version: 16.70.

Unfortunately, my add-in was not designed to be compatible with the Mac operating system. However, I have been unable to find any tutorials or guidance on how to disable this option. I need to find a solution to publish my add-in without Mac support.

My add-in is for Excel and the video of the analysis reports a blank page on load the add-in, but I want the analysis to occur only on Windows.

How to disable this option or is there any other solution to publish my add-in successfully?

**EDIT: I tried to run my add-in in a Mac and in an iPad. In both of them it works. But at the store they displayed a blank page.**

Comment: Would it be a lot of work to offer Mac support? What is different about OS X that stops it working?

Comment: I tryed to run my add-in in a mac and in a ipad. In both of then works. But at the store they related a blank page.

Comment: Have you published your add-in? What did you finally do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option to disable a specific platform. To pass validation, your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define (for more information, see [section 1120.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#11203-functionality) and the [Office Add-in application and availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets) page).

The following are the minimum client versions of Office on Mac that support Office Add-ins.

- Word version 15.18 (160109)
- Excel version 15.19 (160206)
- PowerPoint version 15.24 (160614)